# Why does this array has no attribute 'log10'?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to calculate the log10 of an ndarray, but I'm getting the following error: AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'log10', by doing some research I found that it has to do with the way python handles numeric values, but I still can't get why I'm getting this error.

```
>>> hx[0:5,:]
array([[0.0],
       [0.0],
       [0.0],
       [0.0],
       [0.0]], dtype=object)
>>> type(hx)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> type(hx[0,0])
<class 'float'>
>>> test
array([[ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.]])
>>> type(test)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> type(test[0,0])
<class 'numpy.float64'>
>>> np.log10(test)
array([[-inf],
       [-inf],
       [-inf]])
>>> np.log10(hx[0:5,:])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'log10'
>>> np.log10(np.float64(0))
-inf
>>> np.log10([np.float64(0)])
array([-inf])
>>> np.log10([[np.float64(0)]])
array([[-inf]])
>>> np.log10(float(0))
-inf
>>> np.log10([[float(0)]])
array([[-inf]])
```

I thought the reason was that type(hx[0,0]) is a Python float class, but I was able to calculate the log10 of a float class as well. I'm pretty sure I'm supposed to cast some kind of value so it can be handled as a parameter for numpy.log10(), but I can't spot it.

Comment: How did you create `hx`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data type of `hx` is `object`.  You can see that in the output, and you can check `hx.dtype`.  The objects stored in the array are apparently Python floats.  Numpy doesn't know what you might have stored in a object array, so it attempts to dispatch its functions (such as `log10`) to the objects in the array.  This fails because Python floats don't have a `log10` method.

Try this at the beginning of your code:

```
hx = hx.astype(np.float64)
```

Comment: If the error is triggered by a call within numpy, why isn't that code given in the traceback?