# AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'log10'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am attempting to find the log slope of a ton of short series using sklearn.LinearRegression. The data is being pulled from rows of a pandas dataframe and looks like:

```
bp01    1.12
bp02    1.12
bp03    1.08
bp04    0.99
bp05    1.08
bp06    1.19
bp07    1.17
bp08    1.05
bp09     0.8
bp10    0.96
bp11    0.97
bp12    1.12
bp13    0.91
bp14    0.96
bp15    1.05
bp16    0.93
bp17    0.97
bp18    0.92
bp19    0.89
bp20       0
Name: 42029, dtype: object
```

However, when I attempt to use np.log10, on the series I get the following error:

```
In[27]: test.apply(np.log10)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-27-bccff3ed525b>", line 1, in <module>
    test.apply(np.log10)

  File "C:\location", line 2348, in apply
    return f(self)

AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'log10'
```

I am not sure why this error is being raised, [np.log10](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.log10.html) should work with numpy.float64 from what I am seeing. Ideas?

Comment: Try this: `test.apply(lambda x: np.log10(x))`

Comment: test is a pd.series though. The apply should be passing each value in the series the np.log10 command though right?

Comment: See if [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46995041/why-does-this-array-has-no-attribute-log10) is a duplicate.

Comment: You have called a float variable `np`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`numpy.log10` is a "ufunc", and the method `Series.apply(func)` has a special test for numpy ufuncs which makes `test.apply(log10)` equivalent to `np.log10(test)`.  This means `test`, a Pandas `Series` instance, is passed to `log10`.  The data type of `test` is `object`, which means that the elements in `test` can be arbitrary Python objects. `np.log10` doesn't know how to handle such a collection of objects (it doesn't "know" that those objects are, in fact, all `np.float64` instances), so it attempts to dispatch the calculation to the individual elements in the `Series`.  To do that, it expects the elements themselves to have a `log10` method.  That's when the error occurs: the elements in the `Series` (in this case, `np.float64` instances) do not have a `log10` method.

A couple alternative expression that should do what you want are `np.log10(test.astype(np.float64))` or `test.astype(np.float64).apply(np.log10)`.  The essential part is that  `test.astype(np.float64)` converts the data type of the `Series` object from `object` to `np.float64`.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error message when using the standard deviation (np.std) instead of np.log10:

> 'AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'sqrt',

and this although I had previously converted the Pandas object X to a numpy array via `np.asarray(X)`.

I could solve this problem by applying the above-mentioned solution:

```
X = pd.read_excel('file.xls')
Y = np.asarray(X).astype(np.float64)
Z = np.std(Y,axis=0)
```