# Optimizing a function where one of the parameters is an array

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I want to optimize a function by varying the parameters where two of the parameters are actually arrays. I've tried to do

```
...
# initial parameters
params0 = np.array([p1, p2, ... , p_array1, p_array2])
p_min = minimize(myfunc, params0, args)
...
```

where the pj's are scalars and p_array1 and p_array2 are arrays of the same length, but this gave me an error saying

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I've also tried passing p_array1 and p_array2 as scalars into myfunc and then create predetermined arrays from those two inside myfunc (e.g. setting p_array1 = p_array1*np.arange(6) and similarly for p_array2), eliminating the error, but I don't want them to be predetermined -- instead I want 'minimize' to figure out what they should be.

Is there any way that I can utilize one of Scipy's optimization functions without getting this error while still keeping p_array1 and p_array2 as arrays and not scalars?

**EDIT**

Sorry for being very broad but here is my code:

**NOTE**: 'myfunc' here is actually *norm_residual* .

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def f(yvec, t, a, b, c, d, M, theta):
    # the system of ODEs to be solved
    x, y = yvec
    dydt = [ a*x - b*y**2 + 1, -c*x - d*x*y + np.sum(M * np.cos(theta*t)) ]
    return dydt

ni = 3 # the number of periodic forcing functions to add to the DE system
M = 0.56*np.random.rand(ni) # the initial amplitudes of forcing functions
theta = np.pi/6*np.arange(ni) # the initial coefficients of the forcing functions

# initialize the parameters
params0 = [0.75, 0.23, 1.0, 0.2, M, theta]

# grabbing the data to be used later
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
y_data = data['Y']

N = y_data.shape[0] #20
t = np.linspace(0, N, N) # array of t values to integrate over
yvec0 = [0.3, 0.34] # initial conditions for x and y respectively

def norm_residual(params, *args):
    """
    Computes the L^2 norm of the residual of y and the data (y as defined above).
    Input:    params = array of parameters (scalars or arrays) for the DE system
              args = other arguments to pass into the function f or to use
                   to compute the residual.
    Output: err = L^2 error of the solution vector (scalar).
    """
    data, yvec0, t = args
    a, b, c, d, M, theta = params
    sol = odeint(f, yvec0, t, args=(a, b, c, d, M, theta))
    x = sol[:, 0]; y = sol[:, 1]
    res = data - y
    err = np.linalg.norm(res, 2)
    return err

from scipy.optimize import minimize

p_min = minimize(norm_residual, params0, args=(y_data, yvec0, t))
print(p_min)
```

And the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model_ex_1.py", line 62, in <module>
    p_min = minimize(norm_residual, params0, args=(y_anom, yvec0, t))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py", line 354, in minimize
    x0 = np.asarray(x0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 482, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: Can you post full traceback and source of `myfunc`?

Comment: Whatever you do, you have to use a flattened-view in regards to minimize-API! If there are params: ```p1, p2, p3, p_array1, p_array2``` where ```len(p_array1)``` = N and ```len(p_array2)``` = M, you will want to provide an x0 of size ```3 + N + M``` and you could unpack those in your function (probably first lines) like ```p1, p2, p3 = x[:3]```, ```p_array1 = x[3:3+N]``` and ```p_array2 = x[3+3+N:]``` and do whatever you want to do on those mixed types. ```params0``` could probably be created by ```np.hstack((p1, p2, p3, p_array1, p_array2))``` or in some similar way (under some assumptions).

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko I have edited my post to include more of the code and traceback. See the note above.

Comment: Why was my post down-voted? I have put in some research effort as indicated in my trial and errors as shown in my post. If it was due to clarity or usefulness, I've also included the function definition of my system of ODEs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! The solution that I found to work was to change

```
params0 = [0.75, 0.23, 1.0, 0.2, M, theta]
```

in line 6 to

```
params0 = np.array([ 0.75, 0.23, 1.0, 0.2, *M, *theta], dtype=np.float64)
```

and in my function definition of my system of ODEs to be solved, instead of having

```
def f(yvec, t, a, b, c, d, M, theta):
    x, y = yvec
    dydt = [ a*x - b*y**2 + 1, -c*x - d*x*y + np.sum(M * np.cos(theta*t)) ]
    return dydt
```

I now have

```
def f(yvec, t, myparams):
    x, y = yvec
    a, b, c, d = myparams[:4]
    ni = (myparams[4:].shape[0])//2 # halved b/c M and theta are of the same shape
    M = myparams[4:ni+4]
    theta = myparams[ni+4:]
    dydt = [ a*x - b*y**2 + 1, -c*x - d*x*y + np.sum(M * np.cos(theta*t)) ]
    return dydt
```

**NOTE**: I had to add "dtype=np.float64" for 'params0' because I was getting the error

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'cos'
```

when I did not have it there and it appears that 'cos' does not know how to handle 'ndarray' objects. The workaround can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47208473/attributeerror-numpy-float64-object-has-no-attribute-log10).

Thanks everyone for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put a list in a numpy array if the other elements are scalars.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> foo_array = np.array([1,2,3,[5,6,7]])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    foo_array = np.array([1,2,3,[5,6,7]])
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you post `myfunc`
but you can do this -

```
def foo():
    return [p0,p1,p2..pn]

params0 = numpy.array([foo(), p_array1, p_array2])
p_min = minimize(myfunc, params0, args)
```

OR from [Multiple variables in SciPy's optimize.minimize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670333/multiple-variables-in-scipys-optimize-minimize?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

```
import scipy.optimize as optimize

def f(params):
    # print(params)  # <-- you'll see that params is a NumPy array
    a, b, c = params # <-- for readability you may wish to assign names to the component variables
    return a**2 + b**2 + c**2

initial_guess = [1, 1, 1]
result = optimize.minimize(f, initial_guess)
if result.success:
    fitted_params = result.x
    print(fitted_params)
else:
    raise ValueError(result.message)
```

Comment: I have edited my post and included more code if it helps. I will try to work on this idea.