# AttributeError on long integers for Numpy's arccosh

Tags: python, numpy

I came across an unpredicted `AttributeError` when using the `arccosh` in Numpy. Here it is with Python 2:

```
>>> from numpy import arccosh
>>> arccosh(123456789012345678901)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'long' object has no attribute 'arccosh'
```

I found a similar error in Python 3.

Making the number a bit lower helps:

```
>>> arccosh(12345678901234567890)
44.65298496976247
```

While floats also works:

```
>>> arccosh(10**20)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'arccosh'
>>> arccosh(10.**20)
46.74484904044086
```

The exception also pops up for other functions, e.g., `arcsinh`, `log10` and `sin`.

I suppose that the numbers are too long for `numpy.uint64`

```
>>> big = np.array([10**18], dtype=np.uint64)
>>> big = np.array([10**20], dtype=np.uint64)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

and that Numpy does not handle the `numpy.object`.

```
>>> big = np.array([10**20], dtype=np.object)
>>> arccosh(big)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'arccosh'
```

Python's `acosh` in the `math` module works:

```
>>> from math import acosh
>>> acosh(10**20)
46.74484904044086
```

I see an explanation here [AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'log10'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47208473/attributeerror-numpy-float64-object-has-no-attribute-log10) so while the error is explanable it is a bit surprising.

Comment: I'd say it's a NumPy bug, if it doesn't handle large integers properly. At least the error message should be clearer. Though I assume this bug is already reported somewhere on the NumPy repository.

Comment: Yup, reported as a NumPy bug (only six days ago): https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/11407