# 'Float' object has no attribute 'log'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, logarithm

I have a time series with price information in column `price`.  When I tried to create a new column `ln_price` by taking the `ln` of column `price` I got an error:

> AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'log'

Can someone help me understand why this would be and how it can be fixed?

Thanks!

```
df['ln_price'] = np.log(df['price'])
```

Comment: Are you sure this is all the relevant code?

Comment: You have a float variable `np` in scope.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47208473/attributeerror-numpy-float64-object-has-no-attribute-log10/47208873#47208873

Comment: @AndyHayden Same thought.

Comment: @Tony, your question is not complete.  It will be much easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that anyone can copy and run to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Thank you, absolutely. Like, what is the variable `df`? Because that would be valuable information.

Comment: Like @WarrenWeckesser, I suspect the `dtype` of `df['price']` is `object.  `numpy` functions like this can't operate directly on object arrays.  Instead they try to delegate the action to a corresponding method of the objects - hence this error.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding the `pandas` tag.

Answer (score 10):

As pointed out by [warren-weckesser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1217358/warren-weckesser) this can also happen if you use dtype object (and in fact this is likelier the issue you are facing):

```
>>> s = pd.Series([1.0], dtype='object')
>>> s
0    1
dtype: object
>>> np.log(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'log'
```

You can address this by setting the dtype to float explicitly:

```
>>> np.log(s.astype('float64'))
0    0.0
dtype: float64
```

In your case:

```
np.log(df['price'].astype('float'))
```

Note: You can have more control using [`to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html).

---

First/alternative answer:

You have a float variable `np` in scope.

The problem is that:

```
import numpy as np
np = 1
np.log
```

is perfectly valid python.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np = 1.
>>> np.log
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'log'
```

The solution is not to use `np` are a variable name, or other popular import abbreviations pd or dt etc.
You can pick this kind of error up using a linter.

Comment: This is a possible source of the error, but not the only one.  The error also occurs if `df['price'].dtype` is `dtype('O')` (i.e. the data type is `object` instead of `float64`).  This is not unusual when working with Pandas.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Well, either way, we can 100% say that the problem is not part of the code you posted. Because your code works.

Comment: @Finomnis, I didn't post any code in this question.  What code are you talking about?

Comment: `df['ln_price'] = np.log(df['price'])`

Comment: You assumed that `df` is a Python dictionary with a `float` value.  I can create an example that reproduces the error when `df` is a Pandas DataFrame.  See my answer to the question I linked to in a comment on the question.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'log'`, the code you cide would not give that error.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser "You assumed that df is a Python dictionary with a float value", no. That specific error can only happen at `.log`...

Comment: @AndyHayden: `np.log(pd.Series(np.random.rand(10), dtype=object)) `, where `pd` is `pandas`.

Comment: Even simpler: `np.log(pd.Series([1.0, 'NA', 3.0])) `

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser ooh, interesting. So it's to do with the dtype object, that's really weird.

Comment: @Finomnis looks like warren was correct: it's about the dtype! (I updated this answer to have some info), really weird.

Comment: Oh. What? That is super weird, but I think I don't know enough about pandas. I still think if OP used pandas, he should have mentioned it *somewhere*.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is outside of the code that you posted. Your code works. At least if I assume that `df` is a dict. But I cannot assume anything else, because your question does not specify it.

```
import numpy as np

df = {'price': 10.0}
df['ln_price'] = np.log(df['price'])

print(df)
```

```
{'price': 10.0, 'ln_price': 2.3025850929940459}
```

Comment: `df` is a common variable name for a `pandas.DataFrame`.  Its indexing can look a lot like a dict's.