# statsmodels has trouble predicting on formulas using functions like log on rows of heterogeneous type

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I have a pandas DataFrame whose rows contain data of multiple types. I want to fit a model based on this data using `statsmodels.formula.api` and then make some predictions. For my application I want to make predictions a single row at a time. If I do this naively I get `AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'log'` for the reason described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47208873/2829764). Here's some sample code:

```
import string
import random
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Generate an example DataFrame
N = 100
z = np.random.normal(size=N)
u = np.random.normal(size=N)
w = np.exp(1 + u + 2*z)
x = np.exp(z)
y = np.log(w)
names = ["".join(random.sample(string.lowercase, 4)) for lv in range(N)]
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": x, "y": y, "names": names})

reg_spec = "y ~ np.log(x)"
fit = smf.ols(reg_spec, data=df).fit()
series = df.iloc[0]  # In reality it would be `apply` extracting the rows one at a time
print(series.dtype)  # gives `object` if `names` is in the DataFrame
print(fit.predict(series))  # AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'log'
```

The problem is that `apply` feeds me rows as `Series`, not `DataFrame`s, and because I'm working with multiple types, the `Series` have type `object`. Sadly `np.log` doesn't like `Series` of `object`s even if all the `object`s are in fact `float`s. Swapping `apply` for `transform` doesn't help. I could create an intermediate DataFrame with only numeric columns or change my regression specification to `y ~ np.log(x.astype('float64'))`. In the context of a larger program with a more complicated formula these are both pretty ugly. Is there a cleaner approach I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Although you said you don't want to create an intermediate DataFrame with only numeric columns because it's pretty ugly, I think using [`select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) to create a numbers-only subset of your Series on the fly is quite elegant and doesn't involve large code modifications:

```
series = df.select_dtypes(include='number').iloc[0]
```

Comment: Does this work for you? On my end, i get: `PatsyError: Number of rows mismatch between data argument and np.log(x) (2 versus 100)
    y ~ np.log(x)
        ^^^^^^^^^`

Comment: @ItamarMushkin: yes, it works for me (pandas 0.25.1). Output `float64
0   -3.020539
dtype: float64`. I only had to change `string.lowercase` to `string.ascii_lowercase` which is not related to the issue in question.

Comment: It works for me under 0.23.4. I didn't know about the `df.select_dtypes` method, which is much nicer than supplying my own list.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that dawned on me as I was doing some other work is to convert the `Series` that `apply` gives me into a `DataFrame` consisting of a single row. This works:

```
row_df = pd.DataFrame([series])
print(fit.predict(row_df))
```

Comment: You can also turn a series into a dataframe with `series.to_frame().T`