# sqrt and float data in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have some problem in my code
its result error "AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'float'"

i need solution to solve it

my code

```
def calculateED (pdX, pdY):
arg = (((pdX['NormalTemp']-pdY[0])**2)+
    ((pdX['NormalHumidity']-pdY[1])**2)+
    ((pdX['NormalOutlook']-pdY[2])**2)+
    ((pdX['NormalWindy']-pdY[3])**2)).float()
pdX['ED']= math.sqrt(arg1)
return pdX

dataTest = [64.0,65.0,1.0,1.0]
ngitung = calculateED(dataset, dataTest)
ngitung.sort_values(by=['ED'])
```

but after run this code i have some problem

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-034dd0366562> in <module>
      1 dataTest = (64.0,65.0,1.0,1.0)
      2 #dataTest2 = [72.0,95.0,3.0,0.0]
----> 3 ngitung = calculateED(dataset, dataTest)
      4 #ngitung2 = calculateED2(dataset, dataTest2)
      5 ngitung.sort_values(by=['ED'])

<ipython-input-15-5ae8a365490e> in calculateED(pdX, pdY)
      1 def calculateED (pdX, pdY):
----> 2     arg = (((pdX['NormalTemp']-pdY[0])**2)+
      3         ((pdX['NormalHumidity']-pdY[1])**2)+
      4         ((pdX['NormalOutlook']-pdY[2])**2)+
      5         ((pdX['NormalWindy']-pdY[3])**2)).float()

c:\users\windows\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5463             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5464                 return self[name]
-> 5465             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5466 
   5467     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'float'
```

Comment: You need to change `.float()` to `.astype('float')`

Answer (score 1):

According to this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59297543/why-do-i-get-the-loop-of-ufunc-does-not-support-argument-0-of-type-int-error-f):

> numpy functions require float type argument explicity

Example:

```
import numpy as np
your_array = your_array.float()
output = np.exp(your_array)
```

In your case:

```
def calculateED (pdX, pdY):

    argument = ((pdX['NormalTemp']-pdY[0])**2)+
    ((pdX['NormalHumidity']-pdY[1])**2)+
    ((pdX['NormalOutlook']-pdY[2])**2)+
    ((pdX['NormalWindy']-pdY[3])**2).float()

    pdX['ED']= np.sqrt(argument)

    return pdX
```

Comment: it doesnt work in my code show some error

"AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'float' "

Comment: my code 
`def calculateED (pdX, pdY):
    arg = (((pdX['NormalTemp']-pdY[0])**2)+
        ((pdX['NormalHumidity']-pdY[1])**2)+
        ((pdX['NormalOutlook']-pdY[2])**2)+
        ((pdX['NormalWindy']-pdY[3])**2)).float()
    pdX['ED']= np.sqrt(arg)
    return pdX`
error 
"AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'float'"

Comment: I'm not sure why this is upvoted. You left the problematic line exactly the same. How would this change anything?

Comment: Check that in the end of sum of terms there is `.float()` which according to the referred question in the link solved a common problem. Ah also he edited the question.