# How to compute the sqrt of large numbers with python?

Tags: python, numpy, factorial

I need to compute some prefactors of a formula but run into a problem. It's about the following line:

`x = np.sqrt(np.math.factorial(i1)*np.math.factorial(i2)*np.math.factorial(j1)*np.math.factorial(j2))`

It works for small input variables such as `i1=0, i2=1, j1=0, j2=1`, but as the variables increase, at some point (e.g. for `i1,i2,j1,j2 = 1, 12, 4, 13`) I receive an error: ''loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type int which has no callable sqrt method''. Is this problem due to the fact that the numbers become too large to be handled for the np.sqrt at some point? Any idea how this can be solved? I thought about approximating the factorials, but this does not help if the numbers are simply too large for np.sqrt.

Comment: Can't you compute the product of the individual square roots?

Comment: @mozway Thanks! That's an easier suggestion than expected but it helps in fact - I want to compute indices with values up to 40 or 50, this does not work yet, but now it's at least better than before!

Comment: Looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59297543/why-do-i-get-the-loop-of-ufunc-does-not-support-argument-0-of-type-int-error-f), using `np.sqrt(float(np.math.factorial(i1)*...(j2)))` seems to work.

Comment: `np.sqrt` only works on numbers that fit `int64` dtype.  Larger ones are python `int` and the array has to be `object` dtype.  This error results from trying to apply `sqrt` to such an array. I don't know if `math.sqrt` handles large ints better?

Comment: @hpaulj Great, thank you! Using math.sqrt indeed solves the problem! Also thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Note that the number is converted to a 64 bit double-precision internally so it can overflow since the factorial can be huge (something like >1e380 AFAICT) or just be imprecise.

Comment: `numpy.math` is actually the standard library `math`...