# Failing to use np.std when dealing with pandas.series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two pandas series: `first_error` and `second_error`.

These series have *different* number of values (I emphasize this cause this seems to be the cause of my problem)

When I do

```
std_error=np.std([first_error, second_error])
```

I got the following error

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py:171: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order, subok=True)
*** TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Series which has no callable conjugate method
```

The interesting thing is that in another project I have I do the same without problems (No deprecation there). In this case though the number of elements of both are the same.

Just in case the numpy of the failing one is version 1.20.3 and the one working on is 1.23.3

Anyway, if what I am doing is wrong, how do I calculate the standard deviation of the values in both `first_error` and `second_error`?

Comment: Try to use np.concatenate() before giving it to the np.std method

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59297543/why-do-i-get-the-loop-of-ufunc-does-not-support-argument-0-of-type-int-error-f) was discussed a problem similar to yours, I think. And yes, do you want to find `std` of both `Series` together? `np.std(first_error.append(second_error))` could be it too.