# Error in python3 np.exp(matrix1 * matrix2) - "loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type float which has no callable exp method"

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a function where I need to perform `np.exp(matrix1 @ matrix2)`, but I receive the error message: `loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type float which has no callable exp method`

- `matrix1` is a 210 by 4 matrix of `float` values
- `matrix2` is a 4 by 1 of `float` values
- `matrix1 @ matrix2` is a 210 by 1 of `float` values
- `type(matrix1 @ matrix)` reports `numpy.ndarray`

`numpy.exp()` expects an `array_like` argument so I don't understand why this gags.

Error details:

```
newval = np.exp(matrix1 @ matrix2)

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'exp'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-563-7924faaa390b> in <module>
----> 1 np.exp(matrix1 @ matrix2)

TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type float which has no callable exp method
​
```

Comment: Seems like you've used a variable `np` to store a float value somewhere in your program, and that has overridden the aliasing of `numpy` as `np`.

Comment: What is `(matrix1 @ matrix).dtype`?

Comment: May be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47208873/642070. It could be that when np.exp goes through the series, it assumes that the contained objects will have an `exp` method.

Comment: tdelaney, the dtype is "dtype('O')"

Comment: amzon-ex, I imported numpy as np. np has not been used as a variable.

Comment: tdelaney, that link help solve it! It works with np.exp(np.asarray(matrix1 @ matrix 2).astype(np.float64))

Comment: While the `astype` patches this, you really should figure out where the object dtype comes from.  What's dtype for the those two arrays?

Answer (score 0):

`exp` works on an array of floats:

```
In [186]: arr = np.array([1.,2.,3.])                                                                            
In [187]: np.exp(arr)                                                                                           
Out[187]: array([ 2.71828183,  7.3890561 , 20.08553692])
```

but not if the array dtype is `object`:

```
In [188]: np.exp(arr.astype(object))                                                                            
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'exp'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-188-b80d2a0372d5> in <module>
----> 1 np.exp(arr.astype(object))

TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type float which has no callable exp method
```

Your array may have mixed objects - floats, ints, lists, who knows what.

===

Why is `matrix1 @ matrix2` `object` dtype?  What is `matrix1` and `matrix2`?  `@` is normally a numeric operation, though it has been recently extended to work with object dtypes.  But that is a slower calculation.