# Calculation Geometric Mean

Tags: python, pandas, windows, numpy, math

I have the following dataframe.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrEYC.png)
The data comes from Refinitiv

print(stats.gmean(df4.loc[:,'Price Close']))
I am trying to calculate the geometric mean from this data.
However, I get the following error message:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GOuY.png)

When I create the following dataframe, I do not get an error message

test = pd.DataFrame({
'open':[24, 19, 58, 32, 93, 63, 91, 28, 41,  6],
'close':[2339.42, 1198.09, 2525.13, 514.43, 172.33, 2381.69, 2008.74, 1561.23, 2693.69, 2237.18]
})

print(stats.gmean(df.loc[:,'close']))

Can someone explain to me why in the dataframe at the top does not work? What is the difference? What can I do to solve the problem?

Many thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. refer to the guidelines in posting questions. add the out in the question, as oppose to the images, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but in this case, I think the problem is that data underlying the result of `df4.loc[:,'Price Close']` is stored as an `object` array instead of an array of floating point values. I can reproduce your error with code such as:

```
In [25]: s = pd.Series(np.array([1.0, 2.0, 5.5, 9.0], dtype=object))

In [26]: stats.gmean(s)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'log'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-d026034cc83f> in <module>
----> 1 stats.gmean(s)

~/a202111/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py in gmean(a, axis, dtype, weights)
    273     if not isinstance(a, np.ndarray):
    274         # if not an ndarray object attempt to convert it
--> 275         log_a = np.log(np.array(a, dtype=dtype))
    276     elif dtype:
    277         # Must change the default dtype allowing array type

TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type float which has no callable log method
```

A possible fix is to convert the data to something that the SciPy function is designed to handle.  In my example, I can use the `astype()` method to change the underlying data to a floating point type instead of `object`:

```
In [27]: stats.gmean(s.astype(float))
Out[27]: 3.1543421455299048
```

In your case, you could try passing `df4.loc[:,'Price Close'].astype(float)` to `gmean`.

---

FYI: This question is related to [AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'log10'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47208473/attributeerror-numpy-float64-object-has-no-attribute-log10).  My answer there explains a bit more about what can go wrong when Pandas `object`-based data structures are passed to NumPy or SciPy functions.